# React use this.state or this.props?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm new to react an got a question about components. 
I made a component like this:

```
    class HeaderLabel extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ value: String(this.props.value) });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.value && this.props.value != "" ? <label className="control-label">{this.props.value}</label> : <label className="text-muted">({Translation.getPhrase("EMPTY")})</label>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

HeaderLabel.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string
}

export default HeaderLabel;
```

As you can see I'm using `this.props.value` to display the value. Is this the right way or is it better to use `this.state.value`?

Comment: you don't have to do the `componentWillMount` function at all.You don't have to set the state value to be equal to the props value; you can use `this.props.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Use `this.props.value`.

---

Since you are taking the value directly from the props without mutating it somehow, there is no benefit at all in first storing it in the state and then using `this.state.value`.

Basically this boils down to the fundamental idea of React, which is that you should only ever have *"one source of truth"*. By having `value` both in your props and in the state you have two sources of truth. As  a developer, you should try to have a "master state" which passes the data down to its components.

Sometimes, however rarely, it *can* be a good idea to store the prop value directly to your state. For example, you might want to have a parent component which holds a string which is displayed in your app. This string can be modified in a modal which is opened when clicking the appropriate button. The "temporary under-edit" string would be in the modal-state, whereas the previously saved one still in the master component.

You might find this official blog article helpful: [**You Probably Don't Need Derived State**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

Comment: Ok thanks but when do I use `this.state`? If I want to manipulate the value before?

Comment: "you should try to have a "master state" which passes the data down to its components." - I don't exactly know what you mean by this. Do you have a short example on how to implement this?

Comment: @DetlefDSoost, basically for all relevant data, try to keep only one state in one component. If any children need the data, just pass it down like `<Child foo={this.state.foo} />` and then in Child use `this.props.foo`.

Comment: But why can't i pass the value to the child like `<Child foo={this.props.foo} />`

Comment: @DetlefDSoost you can do that too. My example was the component which has the state. Any children, grand-children, etc, should pass down with `props` like you write.

Comment: I think I didn't get all of that right, sorry. I still don't understand "My example was the component which has the state" - why should a component have a state? Sorry if I fail to see something obvious.

Comment: I think i found it out myself, the properties e.g. `this.props.value` are readonly right? So I need the state e.g. for inputs is that right?

Comment: @DetlefDSoost Correct, it is read-only. You should look at some react tutorials because this is quite fundamental :)

Comment: Yes, you're right I need some tutorials (in case that you know a good one, it would be nice if you can give me the link). 
I tried to use the `this.state.value` now for my input but if its null I get a warning. So I change the value of my input to  `value={this.state.value || ""}` but now I can't edit the input (like its read-only) where is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you are using the props value to display the data which you have received, then using this.props.value makes sense. Props are read-only, means the child is not the owner of that particular data and hence it cannot change anything on that data.

when to use this.state.value, let say a scenario where you get data from parent and you have to do some manipulations on that data before displaying, then, in that case, take props into a state and do the manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  both this.props.value and this.state.value. But first you must answer the following question. Depending on the answer you choose appropriate way of setting the value.
Which component handles the subsequent change of value received from this.props.value:

1. Change of value is coming from Parent component.Then you should use   this.props.value.There is no need for you to assign this.props.value to this.state.value. Because the state is maintained inside parent component.

2.Change is handled by HeaderLabel component itself. Then you should set this.state.value.